# How can I use df.to_sql() with SQLAlchemy AsyncSession/AsyncEgine

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

Expecting similar things where engine is AsyncEngine:

`df.to_sql("temp_data", engine)`

I tried to use:
`await session.run_sync(df.to_sql, name="temp_data")`

but return error:
`AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'cursor'`